# Alternating Least Squares for Baseline Predictor

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, linear-algebra, recommender-system

I am trying to figure out how ALS works when minimizing the following formula:

$\\ \\$

$\text{min}_{\lbrace b_u,b_i \rbrace} \sum_{(u,i)\in \mathcal{K}} (r_{ui} -  \bar{r} - b_u - b_i )^2 + \lambda_{1}(\sum_{u} b_u^{2} +\sum_{i} b_i^{2})$

$\\ \\$

[image]

$\textbf{Question 1}$:
I would like to know how does Alternating Least Squares work in this case. How does it minimize the equation on the picture? The idea of the whole equation that needs to be minimized, I think, it is like when we do a simple linear regression and we have to fit the line. Am I right? In the Lineal Regression we do $(y - \hat y)^2$. In the case of the paper we do $(r_{ui} - \mu -b_{i}-b_{u})^2 +\lambda(...)$

$\textbf{Question 2}$:
This is a chunk of code from someone who coded it. As an example, when he calculates $b_{i}$ he does `dev_i += r - global_mean - bu[u]` and then divides it by `(reg_i + len(self.trainset.ir[i]))`. I do not get why is he subtracting $b_{u}$ if in the equation from the paper, for calculating $b_{i}$ it only subtracts the global mean. Plus, when doing the whole ALS process(in the code), I do not see $\lambda_{1}$ being calculated, it only uses $\lambda_{2}$ ('reg_i'), $\lambda_{3}$ ('reg_u') and the number of epochs / iterations.

```
def baseline_als(self):
    """Optimize biases using ALS.
   Args:
    self: The algorithm that needs to compute baselines.
Returns:
    A tuple ``(bu, bi)``, which are users and items baselines.
"""
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t] bu = np.zeros(self.trainset.n_users)
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t] bi = np.zeros(self.trainset.n_items)

cdef int u, i
cdef double r, err, dev_i, dev_u
cdef double global_mean = self.trainset.global_mean

cdef int n_epochs = self.bsl_options.get('n_epochs', 10)
cdef double reg_u = self.bsl_options.get('reg_u', 15)
cdef double reg_i = self.bsl_options.get('reg_i', 10)

for dummy in range(n_epochs):
    for i in self.trainset.all_items():
        dev_i = 0
        for (u, r) in self.trainset.ir[i]:
            dev_i += r - global_mean - bu[u]

        bi[i] = dev_i / (reg_i + len(self.trainset.ir[i]))

    for u in self.trainset.all_users():
        dev_u = 0
        for (i, r) in self.trainset.ur[u]:
            dev_u += r - global_mean - bi[i]
        bu[u] = dev_u / (reg_u + len(self.trainset.ur[u]))

return bu, bi
```

Just in case I leave the link: [paper](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-dm/s11/SECURE/a1-koren.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question, do you ask what is $b_i$ and $b_u$?

Comment: Hi! $b_{u}$ and $ b_{i}$ are the biases. What I do not understand is how the technique called Alternating Least Squares would work when minimizing $b_{\textbf{*}}$